# I need help downloading lunix on minecraft

Tags: 12.04, installation, java, minecraft, executable

Help! my Minecraft.jar will not run as executable

Comment: i didn't understand the question, are you trying to install minecraft ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean downloading Minecraft on Linux? ;)

If you right click on your .jar file, and select the Proprieties option. Once the new window has opened, select the Permissions tab, and tick the Execute option.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily install Minecraft on Linux by typing  (in a terminal) :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer

Once installed simply run the app, enter (or register) your Minecraft details and you’re all set.

Reference : [Easily Install Minecraft on Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/minecraft-installer-for-ubuntu)